# i commited, pushed to github and pulled a request then cloned again, i tried git pull request, but it gives me an error, why?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

```
$ git pull origin pull/52/head:COC-92-changed-3-files
From https://github.com/.../Conference
 ! [rejected]        refs/pull/52/head -> COC-92-changed-3-files  (non-fast-forward)
```

i commited, pushed the changes to github and pulled a request then cloned the project again, but i now i want to edit the pull request, i tried git pull request, but it gives me an error, why?

Answer (score 1):

While:

```
git pull origin pull/52/head:COC-92-changed-3-files
```

is valid *syntax*, it's not a great idea to use it at all.  What's not clear, here, is what you *should* be doing—so instead, I will describe what you *could* do.  You will have to turn that into what you *should* do.  It will probably include what is called a *force push*, or `git push --force`, but you must be careful with these.

> i commited, pushed the changes to github and pulled a request

I assume here that English is not your first language (and Git-speak isn't even English sometimes anyway ), but *pulled a request* doesn't make much sense here.  I'll guess that you mean *made a pull request*.

> then cloned the project again,

(There is no need to do so, though that's not the source of the error above.)

> but i now i want to edit the pull request, i tried git pull request, but it gives me an error, why?

This all gets a little complicated, and it's helpful to:

- define a GitHub *pull request;* and
- describe what happens in *each Git repository* involved in a GitHub pull request.

It's also important to realize that a GitHub pull request is not a Git concept.  Therefore we'll cover the Git concepts first.

#### Git is all about commits

The first thing to know about Git is that it is all about commits.  While Git *has* branch names, and commits *have* files, Git itself is not about branch names or files.  Git stores, and we will use, *commits*.

Every commit has a unique number, but the numbers aren't simple counting numbers.  They are instead big, ugly, random-looking *hash IDs*.  These numbers aren't actually random at all: they are a cryptographic checksum of all of the bits that make up the commit's content.  This means that no part of any commit can ever be changed, and that every Git everywhere will agree that, given the bits making up some commit, *that* commit gets *that* hash ID.  So two Gits can decide if they both have some commit, just by looking at the number.

Meanwhile, each commit stores two things:

- The main data of a commit are a stored snapshot.  Every file that Git knows about, at the time you (or whoever) make a commit, is stored inside that commit, in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format.  Only Git can read these files, and nothing—not even Git itself—can change them.
- The *metadata* of a commit contain information about that commit, such as who made it—name and email address—and when.  In the metadata for any one commit, Git stores the raw hash ID of the *previous* commit.  So this lets Git work backwards, from the last commit in some chain of commits.

This last part means that, given the commit number—the hash ID—of the *last* commit in some chain of commits, Git can work backwards.  So we can draw a simple chain of commits like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here, the last commit—whose hash ID we're representing with the letter `H`—contains a snapshot and metadata.  In the metadata, commit `H` holds the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  Git can therefore find the actual commit `G`, by this hash ID, and read it to find its snapshot and/or its metadata.  In commit `G`'s metadata, Git has saved the hash ID of earlier commit `F`, so Git can use `G` to find `F`.  Commit `F`, of course, has the hash ID of another, even-earlier commit, and so on.

Hence, as long as we can find the hash ID of commit `H`, we're all good: we can now work backwards, from commit to commit, to see the history: each snapshot, in reverse order, and each commit's metadata (who made it, when, and why—the log message), again, in reverse order.  But how will we find the actual, random-looking ID for `H`?

#### Branch names hold hash IDs

A branch name like `master` or `develop` or `COC-92-changed-3-files` simply holds one hash ID.  This hash ID is, by definition, the *last* commit in the branch.

If we have the name `master` holding hash ID `H`, we can draw that like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

So it's literally the *name* `master` that lets us find commit `H`.  From here, Git can work backwards.

If we have more branch names, they can name more "last commits".  Let's draw an example:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, newbranch
         \
          I   <-- develop
```

Here, both names `master` and `newbranch` name commit `H`, while the name `develop` names commit `I`.  Note that commit `I` leads back, not to `H`, but to `G`.  Commit `G` is thus the parent commit of *both* `H` *and* `I`.

Now that we have three *names*, we have a bit of a problem.  Which *name* are we using?  Let's add the word `HEAD` in parentheses after a branch name to show which name we are using:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), newbranch
         \
          I   <-- develop
```

This tells us that the *name* we are using is `master`.  Since `master` selects commit `H`, commit `H` is the *commit* we are using.

#### Making new commits

Let's use `git checkout` to switch from `master` to `newbranch`:

```
git checkout newbranch
```

Now we have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, newbranch (HEAD)
         \
          I   <-- develop
```

The *name* we are using is now `newbranch`.  We're still on commit `H`!  We have not changed *commits*, but we have changed *branch names*.  Note, by the way, that commits up through `H` are on *all three branches*.  (Commit `I` is only on `develop`.)

I'm going to skip over all the details about how making new commits works, other than to assume that you know how to do it here.  Let's make a new commit now, by changing some file(s) in your work-tree, using `git add`, and running `git commit`.  You'll enter a log message for Git to put in the metadata explaining why you are making this commit, and Git will write out the new commit, which gives it its unique hash-ID number.  Let's draw the new commit now:

```
             J   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I   <-- develop
```

As you can see, Git has put the new commit's hash ID into the *name* `newbranch`, which is the one `HEAD` is (still) attached to.  The parent of new commit `J` is commit `H`: the commit we were on, a moment ago.

#### Sending our commits to another Git repository

Before we send this new commit `J` to another Git repository, let's note that each Git repository *shares* commits.  That is, we'll send our new commit `J` to them, but they'll probably already have all the commits we had before, too.  In other words, both we and they have copies of these commits.  By the magic of the hash IDs, they use the same *numbers* for these shared commits.  So we will only need to send them `J`, not the rest of the commits.

But while Git repositories share the *commits*, they *do not* share the branch names!  Their Git has *its own* branch names.  They might even have their own name `newbranch`, depending on just how new it is.  For now, let's assume that they only have `master` and `develop`, but not `newbranch`.

We will now run:

```
git push <name-of-their-repository> <refspec>
```

We need two names here:

- First, we need a name we use to reach *their* Git.  The name of their repository is also something peculiar to our own Git, and we can use any name we like here, but it's conventional to use the name `origin`, so we will almost certainly use `git push origin` here.
- In the *refspec* part of the `git push`, we give either one branch name, or two branch names with a colon between them.  We could give names that aren't branch names—for instance, we can use tag names—but for this particular case, we just want branch names.

If we want to ask them to set *their* branch named `newbranch`—and we probably do want that—we get to use the simpler syntax, and run:

```
git push origin newbranch
```

here.  Our Git will now call up their Git, and the two Gits will have a conversation.  We'll tell them the commit number of our new commit; they will see that they don't have this commit, and we'll send it to them.  We'll tell them the commit number of our new commit's parent, but if they have that one, we won't have to send that one (or any others, at this point).

Now that they have our new commits (or at least, one new commit), we ask them to create or update *their* branch name.  The branch name we send them is `newbranch`, because we didn't use the syntax that lets us send them a different name from our name.  They check to see if it's OK for them to create or update their `newbranch` the way we asked them to.  Since it's a totally new branch name, the update will be accepted.  If they already had this name, they would do more checking.

#### `git fetch` vs `git push`

Note that in the above steps, we had a new commit for them.  Sometimes, though, *they* have new commits for *us*.

When we want to get commits *from* some other Git, we'll use `git fetch`.  This command just does one thing—well, two things, like `git push`: it *gets* commits, then it updates some name.  Unlike `git push`, though, it doesn't normally update a *branch* name.  (It *can*, but normally, you don't want it to do that.)

Remember, their Git has *their* branch names, and your Git has *your* branch names.  Suppose you have:

```
             J   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I   <-- develop
```

just as before, but *they* have:

```
...--F--G   <-- master
         \
          I   <-- develop
```

That is, suppose *their* `master` is "behind" your `master`.  Or, suppose they have this:

```
...--F--G--K   <-- master
         \
          I   <-- develop
```

so that their `master` is missing commit `H`, but has a commit `K` that you don't have.  If either of these is true, your `git push` step will send *them* commit `H` too, so that they now have, e.g.:

```
          H--I   <-- newbranch
         /
...--F--G--K   <-- master
         \
          I   <-- develop
```

Either way, your `master`'s commit `H` is now in their repository, but *isn't in their `master` branch* at all.

If your Git set your `master` based on their `master`, your Git would *drop* commit `H` from *your* `master`.  So `git fetch` doesn't update your *branch* names at all.  Instead, it updates a different name.

If you're fetching from `origin`, your Git will create or update your *remote-tracking name*, `origin/master`, to remember what is in their `master`.  If they have `develop` and (now) `newbranch`, your Git will create or update your `origin/develop` and `origin/newbranch` too.  Now you will have, in your own repository, this—I'm assuming they have commit `K` here:

```
            J   <-- newbranch (HEAD), origin/newbranch
           /
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G--K   <-- origin/master
         \
          I   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

Through these two `git push` and `git fetch` actions, you have now set things up so that you and they have all the same *commits*.  But your branch names and theirs do not match.  If you now run:

```
git push origin master
```

your Git will call up their Git, see if you have any commits they need (you don't—they have all of yours now), and then ask them to set *their* `master` to name commit `H`, just as yours does.  **They will say *no***, and the reason they say no is that if they did that, they would set *their* Git up like this:

```
            J   <-- newbranch
           /
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G--K   ???
         \
          I   <-- develop
```

They would no longer be able to *find* commit `K` easily (or maybe at all), because Git likes to work *backwards* from the commit found by some branch name.

#### Sidebar: `git clone`

Now that we know that `git fetch` gets commits from some other repository, then creates or updates your own remote-tracking names, we can see how `git clone` works.  What `git clone` does is:

1. create a new, empty directory (or use an existing empty directory you tell it to use);
2. run `git init` to turn that empty directory into an empty repository;
3. create the *remote* named `origin` to store the URL you're cloning from;
4. run any additional configuration you might ask for on the command line;
5. run `git fetch origin` to get *all* the commits from the Git at the URL you're using, which also creates all your remote-tracking `origin/*` names based on their *branch* names; and, last
6. run `git checkout` to create your `master` or other initial branch, from the `origin/master` or other `origin/*` branch you got in step 5.

That's really all it does.  You can run these six steps manually to get the same effect, but of course it's easier to just run `git clone`.

#### Merging

Notice how, in this situation, *your* `master` has a commit (`H`) that theirs lacks, and *their* `master`—your `origin/master`—has a commit (`K`) that yours lacks.  There is no way to pick one of these two commits, yet still have both commits be on your `master`.  In this situation, you might want to *merge* these.

To do this, you can run:

```
git checkout master
git merge origin/master
```

which will do the job.  For space reasons, we won't cover how merge works at all here, but just assume that it works, and therefore makes a new commit, which instead of having just *one* parent, has *two* parents.  We can draw the result like this:

```
            J   <-- newbranch, origin/newbranch
           /
          H--L   <-- master (HEAD)
         /  /
...--F--G--K   <-- origin/master
         \
          I   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

Note how we can start from `L` and now work backwards to *both* `H` *and* `K`.  This means that commits `L`, `H`, `K`, `G`, `F`, and so on—all working backwards—are on your `master` now.

#### Fast-forward operations

We can now run `git push origin master`, which will send our new merge commit `L` to their Git.  Their Git will likely accept our new commit and adjust *their* `master` to identify this new commit `L`.  If they accept this, our Git will adjust our `origin/master`—our memory of their Git's `master`—so that we now have:

```
            J   <-- newbranch, origin/newbranch
           /
          H--L   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
         /  /
...--F--G--K
         \
          I   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

**The reason their Git will be OK with this is that from new merge commit `L`, their Git can reach back to existing commit `K`.**  The operation they did—moving their name `master` forward from shared `K` to newly-shared `L`—is called a *fast-forward*.  After a fast-forward operation, the commit that some name found earlier—in this case `K`—is still find-able by starting at the commit the name finds now, then working backwards.

## Now we can finally talk about pull requests

As I mentioned near the beginning, pull requests are a GitHub feature, not a Git feature.  (Other web hosting services such as Bitbucket and GitLab also have pull requests, but each one does this at least slightly differently, because it's not something built into Git itself.)

Before you can make a pull request, GitHub require that you make what they call a *fork*.  A fork is, in essence, the same thing as a `git clone`, with some extra features added.  In particular, GitHub will remember for you which repository you forked, so that *your* repository—at, say, `github.com/reda-mousawi/proj.git`—is linked to what most people call an *upstream repository*, such as `github.com/main-project/proj.git`.  **GitHub will then give them—your upstream—some (limited) access to *your* fork, whenever you make a pull request.**

Once you have created this fork, you will, in general, use `git clone` to copy this fork to your own computer (e.g., a laptop).  Note that at this point, there are now *three* repositories to keep track of:

- your repository, on (e.g.) your laptop;
- your fork of the upstream repository, on GitHub, which your laptop Git calls `origin`; and
- the repository you forked, which we're calling the upstream repository.

You don't necessarily have a name, or URL, on your laptop to remember the upstream repository.  You can, however, *add* one, and you are often encouraged to do this for various good reasons.  To do that, you might use the following command:

```
git remote add upstream <url>
```

where the *`url`* part here is the URL of the upstream repository, such as `https://github.com/main-project/proj.git`

Once you have added this as a remote, using the name `upstream`—this is the conventional name for the upstream Git repository—you can, on your laptop, run:

```
git fetch upstream
```

which has your Git call up the Git at the upstream URL, find any new commits they have that you need, and create or update remote-tracking names in your Git repository of the form `upstream/*`.

After you set up these *two* remotes, your laptop can keep track of both your fork (which your laptop Git now calls `origin`) and your fork's upstream (which your laptop Git now calls `upstream`).  This isn't actually required to make good pull requests, but it's definitely useful.

#### Making a branch and then a pull request

To make a new branch on your laptop, we start with `git branch` followed by `git checkout`, or `git checkout -b`, which combines the two commands.  We must pick some *existing* commit in the laptop Git that the new branch will name.  We might want to run `git fetch` first, so that we pick up any new commits from whatever repositories have them—`origin` and/or `upstream`—but one way or another, we pick *some* existing commit and make our new branch identify that commit, and then attach the special name `HEAD` to the branch:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, newbranch (HEAD)
```

Now we make one or more commits:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
```

Now we use `git push` to send our new commit(s) to `origin`, creating that same branch name on `origin`.

Now that our GitHub fork, which we're calling `origin` here, has the commits, we can use the GitHub web interface to create a GitHub pull request.  Typically this means clicking various buttons.  We pick the branch `newbranch` and a base branch (such as `master`) and click on a "new pull request" button.  This makes our new commit(s) available to whoever controls the repository that we are calling `upstream` here.  GitHub sends them some messages, e.g., by email, to let them know that we have made this pull request.

It's now up to *them*—the owners of the upstream repository—to decide whether to accept our pull request, or ask us to make changes, or whatever they wish to do.  If they do accept our pull request, *they* have various options:

- They can take our commits as they are, and use a merge commit to add these commits to their repository—the one we're calling `upstream`—so that the only new commit we need to obtain from them is their new merge commit.
- They can use the "rebase and merge" button that they see on their repository to *copy* our commits to new commits, which are now only in their repository.  We need to obtain these new commits from them, and use them instead of our existing commits.
- Or, they can use the "squash and merge" button they see on their repository to make one single new commit that does the same thing as our commits, but does it all in one commit.  This one commit is only in their repository; we need to obtain it from them, and use it instead of our existing commits.

Note that in all three cases, we now need to obtain at least one new commit from the upstream repository.  We *cannot do this* through our GitHub fork!  That's why having the `upstream` *remote* (name for URL) in our laptop Git is convenient, as we can now run:

```
git fetch upstream
```

on the laptop to get the new commit(s) from them.

If the new commit is a merge commit, we can now use `git push` to send this commit to our GitHub fork, if we like.  This update will be a fast-forward to our `origin` fork's pull-request branch *and* a fast-forward to our `origin` fork's `master` (or whatever) branch, so:

```
git push origin upstream/master:newbranch upstream/master:master
```

Note that here, we use the special syntax that says: *send the commit we have in our Git under the name `upstream/master` to the `origin` Git and ask it to set its names `newbranch` and `master`.*

If we're completely done with the name `newbranch`, though, we can just have our Git ask our `origin` fork Git to *delete* the name `newbranch`:

```
git push origin --delete newbranch
```

and then update its `master` as above:

```
git push origin upstream/master:master
```

We can combine these operations into one with:

```
git push origin upstream/master:master :newbranch
```

as the `:newbranch` syntax means send the request: *if it's OK, delete your `newbranch`*, just like `git push origin --delete newbranch` sends.

If the new commit is the result of rebase-and-merge or squash-and-merge, we should generally delete our fork's `newbranch` and update our fork's `master`, just as in the above example.

In all of these cases, we can then update our laptop's own branches, since `origin/*` and `upstream/*` are now all updated.

#### What you are running

When you run:

```
git pull origin pull/52/head:COC-92-changed-3-files
```

you are telling your Git (on your laptop, or whatever computer you are using) to run two Git commands:

- first, run `git fetch origin pull/52/head:COC-92-changed-3-files`;
- then, if that succeeds, run `git merge` with some arguments.

The fetch step is failing, so the second `git merge` does not actually run.

Note that this `git fetch` uses the funny colon-separated syntax that we just showed above for `git push`.  We used this syntax for two cases:

- when we want to delete a branch entirely (as in `git push origin :newbranch`), which isn't really useful for `git fetch`; and
- when we want to use a *different name* in the two Git repositories (as in `git push origin upstream/newbranch:master`).

Here, we're using it to send to `origin` the name:

```
pull/52/head
```

while asking *our* Git to update *our* name:

```
COC-92-changed-3-files
```

That is, we'd like to see *their* `pull/52/head` commit(s), but the name we create-or-update in our repository won't be `origin/pull/52/head` or anything like that.  Instead, the name we want our Git to update is `COC-92-changed-3-files`.

Your `git fetch` step is refusing to do this update *because it is not a fast-forward*.  Go back and re-read what a fast-forward is, and think about what this implies:

- You already have the name `COC-92-changed-3-files`.
- If your Git updates your name `COC-92-changed-3-files`, you will *lose the ability to find* some commits in your repository, through this name.

That might be OK!  It is hard to tell, because I do not have your repository.  However, the name `pull/52/head` is a special GitHub name, that GitHub created for Pull Request #52.  That name is only meaningful in the *target* repository: the one we have been calling `upstream` here.  There is rarely a good reason to look at this, because that particular pull request came from a fork, and the fork itself has some *other* branch name by which this same commit is to be found.

#### Updating a pull request that *we made*

Suppose we make a pull request using the above pattern:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
... edit, git add, git commit as usual ...
git push origin newbranch

# click various web buttons to make pull request
```

At this point, whoever operates the upstream repository looks at our PR and requests some changes.  To make these changes, we will modify files on our own laptop and make *new* commits.  We can make these new commits on our branch `newbranch`, then use `git rebase -i` to copy *all* of our commits, from before the PR and after the updates, into a new-and-improved series of commits.

Now that we have this new-and-improved series of commits on our laptop, our own Git has this:

```
          I--J   <-- origin/newbranch
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I'-J'  <-- newbranch (HEAD)
```

where `I'` is our new and improved variant of commit `I`, and `J'` is our new and improved variant of commit `J`.

What we need to do now is send commits `I'` and `J'` to `origin`—not to `upstream`, but rather, directly to `origin`—and then *command* the Git at `origin` to make *its* `newbranch` point to commit `J'` instead of commit `J`.

To accomplish this, we will run:

```
git push --force origin newbranch
```

which sends to our GitHub fork Git a *command*, rather than a polite request.  The command says that it should make *its* `newbranch` point to commit `J'`, not commit `J`, even though that will make it lose track of commit `J`.  That, after all, is exactly what we want: commit `J'` is the new-and-improved variant, so it *should* forget all about `J`.

As soon as we do this `git push --force`, our GitHub fork is updated, and the PR is *automatically updated* so that whoever is at upstream can look at the new and improved commits.  By making the original pull request, we told GitHub that it should offer, to the Git we call `upstream`, the commits on `newbranch` on our fork.  Since we just *replaced* those commits with new-and-improved commits, GitHub knows to offer the new-and-improved commits directly.

There is therefore no need to look at what is in `pull/52/head`: we changed what is there by changing what is in our fork's `newbranch`.  So `git pull origin pull/52/head:...` is not actually useful here.

If we've somehow *lost* our `newbranch`, that's when `pull/52/head` can be useful.  We should generally use `git fetch` to obtain it, not `git pull`, because once we've obtained it, we probably do not want to `git merge` it directly just yet.  (If we're sure enough what's in it to `git merge` it, we probably know enough not to have to use `pull/52/head` in the first place.)

Comment: i tried---> git pull origin pull/52/head --- and it worked, but now i see many extra  commits in this pull request (on github), these extra commits wasn't made by me, and they were already merged to the master(remote offcourse)